Missing npm command when installing old version of nodejs in ubuntu 20.04
Previously used working command to install nodejs 10x in wsl2 ubuntu 20.04 (Installed project locally on year 2022/2023)
sudo apt update -y
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
node -v
npm -v

versions returned:
node v10.24.1
npm 6.14.12

However when installing in a different computer in wsl2 ubuntu 20.04, the versions returned are as follows:
node v12.22.9
npm not found

Expected results: install correct (deprecated) version
Current results: installed incorrect (deprecated) version
No matter how much I uninstall/reinstall node, I keep getting the same version
Uninstall command used:
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove nodejs

Note:

I know it is deprecated.
Not in the roadmap to upgrade node/npm
Just need it working on terminal

Reasons to use old node/npm:
Project is using Symfony 3 (also deprecated)

My bad. I updated my question
